# How can I use default categories on WooCommerce products

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I want to use the default WordPress post category for WooCommerce products. How can I register the category taxonomy for the product post type from my theme's `functions.php`?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: So you want to use post categories for products?

Comment: @helgatheviking As you understood the question, would you be so kind as to edit it into a more readable form. That might save it from being closed.

Comment: Sure. How's that?

Comment: @helgatheviking Looks good to me! I guess we just have to wait for the close votes to age away now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `register_taxonomy_for_object_type()` to achieve this. Modified slightly for the product post type, here's the [source](https://pippinsplugins.com/add-already-registered-taxonomy/)

```
add_action('init','add_categories_to_cpt');
function add_categories_to_cpt(){
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'product');
}
```

Comment: i am sory i search in wrong place  but thets work and i thenk you :D

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to come off like a jerk. I do recognize that searching for something all depends on using the right phrases. I'm glad it still works.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. You can have it as either wordpress category or woocommerce.

1. You can duplicate them in database.
2. If you do not need wordpress categories in future, then you can change those categories' taxonomy to "product_cat" in database.

Answer (score 0):

If you registered the taxonomy(category) then you don't need any extra function. You can do that while registering.

```
register_taxonomy(
        'category',
        'product', // Here it is assigned to products
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Category' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'category' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );
```